# Applying filters on results of aggregation in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am stuck with a problem where I need to apply some filters on results of an aggregation in elastic search.

For example, assume that the following are the fields
event_name, location, time, user_id

Now my requirement is to get the user ids who have performed a specific action (lets say "logged_in") in the last one month atleast 5 times. I am able to get the users who have logged_in in the last one month. But how do I filter the results further?

The query I have written is:

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range":{
                       "time":{
                          "from": 1412312824,
                          "to": 1422142824
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "action": "logged_in"
                      }          
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "result": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "user_id"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Sample output:

```
user_id, doc_count
1          10
2          25
3           1
4           2
```

I need to apply filter on the above result. How do I do it?

Comment: you want only the user_id where doc_count is >= to 5 ?

Comment: doc_count >= 5 is just an example. Ideally I would like to apply any filter. Like range filter where I want the users who have done a specific action from 2 to 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just add a `min_doc_count` key to your terms aggregation, like so:

```
...
"aggs": {
    "result": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "user_id",
            "min_doc_count": 5
        } 
    }
}
...
```

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count

Comment: I saw this. But the condition is general. Sometimes the query can also be like users who have done a specific action atmost n times. Like range filter where I want the users who have done a specific action from 2 to 5 times

Comment: I understand. Sounds like your issue is similar to https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4404, which if you scroll way way down recommends the `bucket_selector` aggregation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html).

Comment: Seems too complex for my use case. Also not able to find about reducers in official guide. Anyways, thanks for the answer. Would like to know if there are any other ways to achieve this.